# ¿Cómo ordenar alfabéticamente las palabras de un diccionario por columnas en Python con Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Quisiera ordenar éste diccionario:

| index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | abandona |
| 3 | acero |
| 4 | achilenado |
| 5 | acompañado |
| 6 | ademas |
| 7 | adhiere |
| 8 | administra |
| 9 | agonal |
| 10 | aguirre |
| 11 | ahora |
| 12 | al |
| 13 | alabanza |
| 14 | alegria |
| 15 | algunos |
| 16 | alli |
| 17 | alta |
| 18 | ambito |
| 19 | ambos |
| 20 | america |
| 21 | americana |

Y así sucesivamente...

De manera que cada columna sea una letra del abecedario y las filas las palabras. La salida debería quedar algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilicé muchos métodos pero ninguno me dio resultados, agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, a continuación adjunto el código completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Por favor corrige el formato del código y de tus datos tal como se menciona en las secciones de lectura recomendada.

Comment: Por otra parte, no es muy claro el problema que tienes o lo que te impide realizar lo que deseas. Por lo que veo en el `dataframe` resultante ya tienes varias palabras en una columna, ¿Qué haría falta?

Comment: lo que pasa es que quiero re-ordenar el último dataframe (el que tiene indice 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 y así....) de manera que cada columna sea una letra del abecedario, como la primera imagen de excel

Comment: Pon el código completo en lugar de poner imágenes.

Comment: Por favor, pon el código y la salida _como texto, con formato_. Subir código como imagen [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask].

Comment: Buen día @Jos, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` genérico como ejemplo:

```
    0
0   a
1   ab
2   abc
3   abcd
4   b
5   ba
6   bac
7   bacd
8   c
9   ca
10  cab
11  cabd
```

Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y agrupar con respecto a la primera letra del `string` de la columna que te interesa.

Luego, separar cada elemento de la serie en diferentes columnas dependiendo de la letra con la que empiece, para eso se puede utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) junto con [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)

```
df.groupby([df['0'].str.upper().str[0]]).agg(list)['0'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

```
    0   1   2   3
0               
A   a   ab  abc abcd
B   b   ba  bac bacd
C   c   ca  cab cabd
```

Es casi lo esperado pero los índices y las columnas están invertidos, para arreglarlo utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Y quedaría así:

```
0   A       B       C
0   a       b       c
1   ab      ba      ca
2   abc     bac     cab
3   abcd    bacd    cabd
```

Es importante notar que hay un `0` "extra" hasta arriba a la izquierda, ese es el nombre de la serie con los nombres de las columnas, para quitarlo hacemos

```
columns.name = None
```

Ejemplo completo importando los datos desde un archivo "sample.csv":

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

resultado = df.groupby([df['0'].str.upper().str[0]]).agg(list)['0'].apply(pd.Series).transpose()
resultado.columns.name = None
print(resultado)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
      A     B     C
0     a     b     c
1    ab    ba    ca
2   abc   bac   cab
3  abcd  bacd  cabd
```